# Git not using the right SSH key when pushing to github

Tags: git, ssh

So I have two different github accounts and I've created two different SSH keys for them `id_me` and `id_work`, however when I try to make a git push from to my work account, it authenticates me with my personal SSH key instead.

This what I've done:

Added each SSH key to its respective github account. Then followed the steps to add them to my SSH agent:

```
ssh-add -K id_me
ssh-add -K id_work
```

And set up my `~/.ssh/config` like this:

```
# Personal github account
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_me

# Work github account
Host github.com-work
  HostName github.com
  User git
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_work
```

I'm trying to make some changes to a repo on my work account. First, I make sure to clone it using the proper command:

```
git clone git@github.com-work:test.git
```

However, when I push the changes back up, it throws a permission denied error msg:

```
ERROR: Permission to test.git denied to doctopus.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Also, I notice that when I run `ssh -T github.com-work`, it authenticates me on my **personal** account:

```
Hi doctopus! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

So the issue looks like git is not using the right SSH key when it pushes to github.

Comment: Are you sure the host name is correct ? `github.com-work`

Comment: You'll need `IdentitiesOnly yes` so that ssh doesn't send *all* identities, but only the ones listed under `github.com-work`. You may have other settings that need adjustment too. Until `ssh -T github.com-work` identifies you as your work name, it's getting your home-public-key; poke around to figure out why.

Comment: Thanks @torek, your suggestion worked

Answer (score 2):

`ssh -Tv github.com-work` will display which key is actually used.

That way, you can validate your ~/.ssh/config content.

Double-check the content of the public key registered to your GitHub account, as well as the content of both public keys (`id_work.pub` and `id_me.pub`)